# Trace of matrix logarithm for two invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, matrix-equations, multivalued-functions

Consider an unitary matrix $U$ and an positive definite, invertible and diagonalizable matrix $\rho$ .
Then, if the following identity holds (**i.e., if there are additional $2\pi I$ factor**),
\begin{equation}
\text{Im}[\text{tr}\ln (\rho U)]=\text{Im}[\text{tr}\ln (\rho)]+\text{Im}[\text{tr}\ln (U)],
\end{equation}
where the branch cut of $\ln$ function is taken to be $(-\infty, 0]$, and we assume that eigenvalues of $\rho U$ do not locate at the branch cut.

Wiki only mentions that this identity works for product of positive definite matrix, so I wonder if this holds in case one of the matrix is not positive definite.

Comment: how do you define$\log A$?

Comment: @conrad, thanks for the comment. I define a logarithm of a matrix such that its matrix exponential equals to this matrix.

Comment: @Richard Your description does not unambiguously tell us which matrix $\log A$ is for a given matrix $A$, so it is not a *definition* of the matrix logarithm.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, Thanks for the comments! I am following the definition given in Wiki, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix.